# The modFit function of FME package

Tags: r

Why can't I get the exact value of x?

```
library(FME)
a <- function(x){
  fun=(x-6)^2
  return(fun)
}
modFit(a,p=10,method='BFGS')$par[1]
```

The answer I get is 5.998888, and when the initial value p is different, the answer I get is also different.

However in another case

```
library(FME)
a <- function(x){
  fun=(x-6)^2+0.1
  return(fun)
}
modFit(a,p=11,method='BFGS')$par[1]
```

If the minimum value of the function is not 0, no matter what I set the initial value p to, I can get x to be 6

Another case

```
library(FME)
a <- function(x){
  fun=(x-6)^2-2
  return(fun)
}
modFit(a,p=11,method='BFGS')$par[1]
```

The results obtained by setting different p are also very significantly different. In this example, x is 7.41

Am I using the modFit function incorrectly? My understanding of it is similar to the optim function

Comment: From the documentation of `modFit`: "the function `f` should return either a vector of residuals (of model versus data) or an element of class `modCost`...". In essence, `modFit` tries to minimize the sum of squared residuals (in a regression), you are trying to minimize a given function, those two objectives are not necessarily the same.